# How to fix Jupyter extension activation failed when opening python files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, vscode-extensions

I installed python lately on my macos system and when I try to open a python file I see this error popup about Jupyter extension :
[image]

Comment: Did you run the command in the message?

Comment: If you don't know how to open, you may find it under `help`

Comment: Could you try to install the python extension with another version?  Could you provide the Output for `Python` in the `Output` panel(`View`→`Output`, change the drop-down the upper-right of the `Output` panel to `Python`) and the Output from `Console` under the `Developer Tools` panel (toggle Developer Tools on under `Help`; turn on source maps to make any tracebacks be useful by running `Enable source map support for extension debugging`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ran into this today (I'm on MacOS for my work computer). In my case, **upgrading to the pre-release version** of the Jupyter extension (v2022.5.1001281006) solved it right away.

If you're not an experienced programmer/software engineer, as is the case for me, I suggest trying to upgrade (or roll back) either VS code or the plugin itself before going with your own dev code for the plugin, as with @CAG2 pt2 answer. (Personally, I had trouble finding a 'product.json' file; perhaps you need an insider's build of VS code for that kind of thing [edit]: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api, in which case I think you'd be editing 'package.json').

Answer (score 17):

I had this same issue and finally got it fixed!

---

If you are on an Linux and are using an Arch-based distro with AUR support, simply install the `code-features` package using:

```sh
yay -S code-features
```

or any AUR helper of your choosing.

---

On other operating systems, you should do the following:

Open your VSCode's `product.json`. I do not know where this file is on your operating system, so please do some research.

Look for the following line:

```json
"extensionAllowedProposedApi": [ ...
```

Add the following entry to that array:

```json
"ms-toolsai.jupyter": ["notebookConcatTextDocument", 
    "notebookControllerKind", "notebookDebugOptions", "notebookDeprecated", 
    "notebookEditor", "notebookEditorDecorationType", "notebookEditorEdit", 
    "notebookMessaging", "notebookMime", "notebookCellExecutionState", 
    "portsAttributes", "textDocumentNotebook", "quickPickSortByLabel"]
```

For example, if the line was originally:

```json
"extensionAllowedProposedApi": [ "extension1", "extension2" ]
```

Then change it to:

```json
"extensionAllowedProposedApi": [ "extension1", "extension2", 
    "ms-toolsai.jupyter": ["notebookConcatTextDocument", 
    "notebookControllerKind", "notebookDebugOptions", "notebookDeprecated", 
    "notebookEditor", "notebookEditorDecorationType", "notebookEditorEdit", 
    "notebookMessaging", "notebookMime", "notebookCellExecutionState", 
    "portsAttributes", "textDocumentNotebook", "quickPickSortByLabel"] ]
```

---

Note that with the second method, you will need to edit `product.json` every time you update VSCode.

Comment: Unfortunately the proposed fix for arch linux did not work for me

Comment: Installing a slightly older version of the extension worked!

Comment: Fix worked! You are my hero today!

Comment: Works fine, hero

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same problem (in June 2022). It automatically got solved when other dependencies got downloaded/installed. There were "pylance", "jupyter keymap" and two-three more. Simply try to upgrade, or to downgrade (rollback) like BLT suggested. Regards.